# Why so many differences from player to coaches costs transfer?

Tags: football, finances, transaction, transfer

Why there is a lot of difference in cost transfert from football players to a coaches?

I think in Europe almost all coaches have an agent, so I do not understand why there is so much difference in the negotiations between a coach (not free) and a footballer

For example take a look at [Montella sign to AC Milan](http://www.thescore.com/news/1051395) (where Milan is paying €500,000 to release Montella from his Sampdoria contract)

Comment: What do you mean by prosecutor? Usually a prosecutor is the representative of the state in a criminal trial, but that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @Fillet I mean agent or any other person/society that looks after the interests of the coach

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons could be

- Coaches have longer careers therefore waiting 2-3 years for them to become available is not a big deal. Whereas if a striker is 27, you don't want to wait till their contract expires so you're more willing to pay the high transfer fee.
- Players have a more obvious impact. If you have a player who is scoring 30 goals a season, other clubs are going to want to sign him, and not the coach who coached him.
- There is no precedent for high fees for coaches. It is quite common now to spend tens of millions on a player, whereas those fees are unheard of for a coaches fee.